# How can I solve these problems I'm having with the stretcher and faraday gems?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, sinatra, faraday

On my local machine, I am using `elasticsearch`, `ruby`, `sinatra` and the `stretcher` gem.

I get the following error:

```
faraday.rb:99:in `method_missing': undefined method `load_autoloaded_constants' for #<Faraday::Connection:0x9b9f218> (NoMethodError)
```

The truncated ruby code is:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'stretcher'

configure do
  ES = Stretcher::Server.new('http://localhost:9200')
end

class Products
  def self.match(text)
    ES.index(:products).search size: 1000, query: {
      multi_match: { query: text, fields: [:title, :description] }
    }
  end
end

get "/" do
  erb :index
end

get "/:search" do
  erb :result, locals: { products: Products.match(params[:search]) }
end

post "/" do
  unless ES.index(:products).exists?
    # create index if not exists
    ES.index(:products).create(mappings: {
      product: {
        properties: {
          title: {type: :string},
          price: {type: :integer},
          description: {type: :string}
        }
      }
    })
  end
```

All help gratefully received.

When I install stretcher it installs faraday_middleware-multi_json 0.0.6 and faraday 0.9.0 and faraday_middleware 0.9.1 by default.

Answer (score 2):

I think many of us are facing this issue but I haven't found a single place where you will get a proper instructions.

Steps to resolve "**faraday method missing: load_autoloaded_constants**" error

**1.** go to command line and open stretcher folder under gems folder

```
sudo subl /home/abhinay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/stretcher-1.21.1/
```

**2.** Open  **lib/stretcher.rb**

**Add this line:**  `require 'multi_json'` # line 5

**Remove these line:**

`require 'faraday_middleware/multi_json'` # line 7

```
Faraday.load_autoloaded_constants  # line 8
```

**3.** Open **lib/stretcher/server.rb**

**change**

```
builder.response :multi_json, :content_type => /\bjson$/ #line 9
```

**to**

```
builder.response :json, :content_type => /\bjson$/
```

**and**

`builder.request :multi_json`

**to**

`builder.request :json` # line 11

**4.** Open **spec/lib/stretcher_index_spec.rb**
**change** #line 44

```
block.call.should == %{curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo' -d '#{MultiJson.dump(options)}' '-H Accept: application/json' '-H Content-Type: application/json' '-H User-Agent: Stretcher Ruby Gem #{Stretcher::VERSION}'}
```

**to**

```
block.call.should == %{curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo' -d '#{JSON.dump(options)}' '-H Accept: application/json' '-H Content-Type: application/json' '-H User-Agent: Stretcher Ruby Gem #{Stretcher::VERSION}'}
```

**5.** Open **stretcher.gemspec** change #line 30

```
gem.add_dependency('faraday_middleware', '~> 0.9.0')
```

**to**

```
gem.add_dependency('faraday_middleware', '~> 0.9')
```

**and Remove these lines # line 33 & 34**

```
gem.add_dependency('multi_json', '>= 1.0')
gem.add_dependency('faraday_middleware-multi_json', "~> 0.0.5")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a known Stretcher issue.  Refer to https://github.com/PoseBiz/stretcher/pull/85

Options:
1) Use the prior version of Faraday, e.g. `Gemfile` with:

```
 gem 'faraday', '0.8.9'
```

2) Mirror the changes to address known Stretcher issue 85.

Answer (score 0):

Use this fork/sha of stretcher: https://github.com/whatstherub/stretcher/commit/b09bce05e3ed07d47ab2a408e2ef674738dc8b28